# Make an sdl window not show up on the menubar

Tags: c, window, sdl, sdl-2

Im trying to make a widgets application in **C** with **SDL2** and I've been wondering if there is anyway of making an SDL2 window not show up on the menu/window bar?

[To hide something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tarSe.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [SDL_WindowFlags](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowFlags), `SDL_WINDOW_SKIP_TASKBAR` is what you are looking for.

```
Uint32 flags = SDL_WINDOW_SKIP_TASKBAR;
SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    /* ... */
    flags
);
```

Comment: @datawater Consider pressing the checkmark next to the answer to mark your question as solved.